# In what situations is octal base used?

Tags: language-agnostic, octal

I've seen binary and hex used quite often but never octal. Yet octal has it's own convention for being used in some languages (ie, a leading 0 indicating octal base). When is octal used? What are some typical situations when one would use octal or octal would be easier to reason about? Or is it merely a matter of taste?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Octal is used as a shorthand for representing file permissions on UNIX systems. For example, file mode `rwxr-xr-x` would be `0755`.

Comment: But since the values only go from 0-7, isnt it technically the same as Decimal or Hexidecimal?

Comment: No, because in decimal you'd also have 8 and 9, and so on.

Comment: @Neil no, because those would give you different numerical values -- `0x755` is `011101010101` in binary, whereas `0755` is `111101101`. The former, then, would mean something completely different in unix file permissions.

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking each digit was applied seperately. "755" of course is very different than its decimal counterpart.

Answer (score 46):

Octal is used when the number of bits in one word is a multiple of 3, or if the grouping of the bits makes sense to notate in groups of 3. Examples are

- ancient systems with 18bit word sizes (mostly historical)
- systems with 9bit bytes (mostly historical)
- unix file permissions with 9bits  (3*3bits, "rwxr-x---" 0750)
- unix file permissions with 12bits (the same as the 9bit version but adding three bits in front for setuid, setgid, and sticky, 01777 but the letters are more complicated here)

I have not encountered any uses of octal other than unix file permission bits during my about 25 years in IT.

If the number of bits in your word is a multiple of 4, however, *please do use hex*, by all means.

Comment: This is a non-answer. A number system is not “used” by its definition. The question asked for example cases where octal is applied.

Comment: Octal is also used in tar archive headers. The file size, for example, is encoded in ASCII octal representation. Do `hexdump -C` on a tar file and you'll see quite a lot of octal digits in there.

Answer (score 7):

Octal is used when the syntax is a relic from the ages when it perhaps made sense on some platform (system words haven't always been a multiple of 8 bits). Nowadays hex is the thing to use.

Answer (score 7):

One of the main reasons octal used to be more frequently used was that it is easier to convert between octal and binary in your head than hex to binary: you only have to remember the binary representation of the 8 octal digits (0-7).

Back in the days when debugging meant reading register contents from a row of LEDs, or entering data with an array of toggle switches, this was a big concern. The panels on many of these early computers grouped the LEDs and switches in groups of threes to facilitate this.

However, hex began to win out as word sizes that are multiples of 8-bit bytes began to win out, and the need to read and enter data in binary became unecessary (with console text UI and later GUI debuggers).

Answer (score 6):

Didn't think of this but Digital displays!

Several other uses from:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Answer (score 4):

If birds could count, my guess would be that they use octal.  While most birds have 3 digits on their feathered "hands", most are [Tetradactyly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactyly#Tetradactyly), meaning 4 toes on each foot.

Comment: Oh and Mickey mouse, too ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In avionics, ARINC 429 word labels are almost always expressed in octal.

Answer (score 1):

Music, as long as you stay away from (most) sharps and flats.

Comment: .... What? One "traditional" (i.e. on piano) octave has 12 sounds. 12. Not 7. And you can't avoid sharps and flats in anything even remotely serious.

Comment: There are 12 notes on the chromatic scale, but only 7 on the diatonic scale. Musical notes are labeled according to the diatonic scale, A-G, which is an octal numbering system. Solfège also travels the diatonic scale. True, the other 5 semitones in between require additional marks to represent, but the OP asked about *uses* of octal numbering, NOT information theory, where of course representing music would require more than 3 bits per note.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there are a few places that windows and javascript automatically decide that a number prefixed with a zero is octal and convert the number.

In windows if you ping and address like 10.0.2.010 it will actually ping 10.0.2.8

Windows also does this if you enter it as the ip/dns address for the computer

Though it is deprecated, Javascript does this by default on some functions like parseInt if you do not specify a radix  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Anything that uses Windows Sockets [`inet_addr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will exhibit this documented behaviour.

Comment: Perl too, apparently.

Comment: C works this way (where a "0" prefix causes the numeric literal to be interpreted in octal notation), both in the language itself and in the standard library. It is therefore not surprising in the least that operating systems like Windows would have inherited this behavior.