# python + variable doing wrong math

Tags: python

I have posted data coming from a webform, and I am trying to convert lb's to oz's for shipping labels.

The webform is set to just post numbers.

```
<input type="number" step="1" name="lbs" id="lbs" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Lb's" tabindex="7">
```

Below is the python code

```
llb = request.form['lbs']
lw = (llb*16)
return lw
```

It always returns the wrong number.

2 for llb returns 2222222222222222 when it should be 32. I tried messing with 0o16 etc with no success.

I even tried making sure llb was an int with

```
llb = int(request.form['lbs'])
```

I can't figure this out for the life of me. For all I know I could be over thinking this.

I even tried everything mentioned on [Wrong math with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894182/wrong-math-with-python) and a few others I could find simlar.

Comment: `llb` is a string, not an integer. String multiplication means *repetition*.

Comment: Add a `print(type(llb))` to make sure it's a `int` and not `str`.

Comment: Again, please paste the result of `print (type(llb))`. And where does this `request` module comes from? I know `requests` or `urllib.request`, but that seems none of them. Please specify your version of python too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`llb` variable is a string. You need to cast it if you want an int.

`'2'*16` will print 16 times the character 2.

If `llb` is supposed to be an int, just do:

`lw = (int(llb)*16)`

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable That is what i get with that. I had tried that earlier :/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
llb = request.form['lbs']
lw = (int(llb)*16)
return lw
```

Since your `request.form['lbs']` is `str` type you need to cast it to `int` type before multiplication. 
Multiplication sign `*` works with strings in such a way that it copies them given amount of times.

Example:

```
'^'*5
>> '^^^^^'
```

### EDIT

Your problem seems to be that you have overwritten the built-in `int` with some other variable.

Example:

```
>>> lbs = '2'
>>> lbs
'2'
>>> lw = lbs*16
>>> lw
'2222222222222222'
>>> lw = int(lbs)*16
>>> lw
32
>>> int = 7
>>> lw = int(lbs)*16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del int
>>> lw = int(lbs)*16
>>> lw
32
```

You should never overwrite built-in names such as `int`, `list`, `set`, `dict` and so on: [Why can you assign values to built-in functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865363/why-can-you-assign-values-to-built-in-functions-in-python)

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable That is what i get with that. I had tried that earlier :/

Comment: you must have overwritten `int` in your namespace. If you have any place in your code when you do something like `int = some_variable` or `int = 5`, you should change that `int` name to something other - you should never use built-in names for your variables. ==EDIT== Added example where I reproduce your problem.