# Why does this code only print zero?

Tags: php, types

Why does this code only print zero? Why does it not print the value of a?

```
<?php
$a=099;
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: Not valid octal

Comment: echo is meant to print a `string` and your `$a` is an integer, try this instead - `$a='099'; echo $a;`

Comment: it did exactly what you asked it to do. if you want to output as a string you would need to set `$a='099';`

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi echo can print integers. They're automatically converted to strings in that context. I think the issue here is just that the OP did not realize what the leading zero was doing.

Comment: If you're wondering what the point of octal is, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609426/in-what-situations-is-octal-base-used) has some good answers about that, although there are also some silly ones there. [Here is a better one on Software Engineering.](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98692/where-are-octals-useful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ultimater points out, you have assigned $a to an invalid octal number.

A numeric value (known as an "integer literal" in this case) prefaced with a zero is assumed by the parser to be an octal (base 8) number.  As your number contains nines, which are not in the base (base 8 digits are 0-7), it's not valid and the parser evaluates it to zero.

For example, this *does* work:

```
$a = 077;
echo $a;  //63
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 1):

The number started with '0' is Octal number.
But Octor number has 0~7, has no 8, 9.
so `$a` is set zero.
If you want to print '099', try

```
$a = '099'; 
echo $a;   //print 099
```

If you want to get number, try

```
$a = 045; 
echo $a;    //print 37(Decimal number)
```